# How can I make an empty div display between the header and footer?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an empty `div` between my `header` and my `footer`, as my webpage has a `background image` which I would like to be clear of any elements.

The full code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Cilvako/4105a0oy/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-size: 16px;
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/200/300') no-repeat fixed center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
/*-------------- HEADER -----------------------*/

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
#header h1 {
  font-family: "Frijole", cursive;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#header ul {
  font-family: "Frijole", cursive;
  float: right;
  padding: 20px 20px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
#header ul,
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
/*-------------- EMPTY DIV -----------------------*/

#empty_div {
  height: 800px;
}
/*-------------- FOOTER -----------------------*/

#footer {
  clear: both;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
#footer p {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.social_icon {
  display: inline;
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25;
  margin-right: 0.3215rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">

  <a href="index.html" id="logo">
    <h1 class="headings">THE 100 DAYS PROJECT</h1>

  </a>


  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="new_treehouse.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div id="empty_div">

</div>

<div id="footer">
  <a href="http://twitter.com/cilvako">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="Twitter Logo" class="social_icon">
  </a>
  <a href="http://facebook.com/">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="Facebook Logo" class="social_icon">
  </a>

  <p>&copy; 2016 Silvia Bogdan</p>

</div>

</body>
```

Can I make the empty `div` to display and take the whole `height` of the page (so it creates empty space between the `header` and the `footer`)?

I have set a value (`min-height: 800px`, for example), but when resizing the browser (I tried displaying on different devices using Developer Tools), the `footer` it's placed all over the place and never at the of bottom of the page.

Comment: Don't try to use an element to position another element. Have you looked into the css property `position`? `position:fixed` is probably what you want for your footer. How to make your `#empty_div` to take up the remaining space between your header and footer would then be another question.

Comment: @CasiaHospi if you are still interested you can take a look at my answer, that doesn't use neither `position` or `width/height`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is this what you want to do.
Open it in full screen to see a better result.

```css
#header{
  background: #ebebeb;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#footer{
  background: #dbdbdb;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="header">
  <h1>
  Header
  </h1>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <h1>
  Footer
  </h1>
</div>
</body>
```

By default the `position` of a div is `static`. You need to make it `absolute` or `fixed` and than add properties like `top` or `left` or `bottom` or `right` to place the element exactly where you want.

Here are some links where you can see the difference between `position: absolute;` and `position: fixed;`.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

I hope this helps.

Comment: actually the default position of every element is static

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: I am glad I could help you. :)

Comment: @CasiaHospi make sure to mark this answer as the correct one if it solved your problems

Comment: don't refer to w3cshools. it is not recommended, instead, use W3C or MDN

Comment: also you have horizontal scrollbar :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see that before. It was because of the `<h1>` element. It had the `width` of `100%` and it was pushed to the right by `20 px` because of the parent div's `padding:20px;`. I just removed the padding from the `#header` and `#footer` divs to fix this, but again, there are a lot of ways of doing this, and another would be by using the `overflow` property for the divs or using frameworks like Bootstrap. :)

Comment: overflow:hidden is always a ugly hack, and bootstrap is a overkill for this

Comment: You're right about them. 
However `overflow` comes in handy when you don't have time to do something right.
And Bootstrap comes in handy when you want to work on big projects. I have recently done something like that and that's why I mentioned it.

Comment: If you do right from the start you won't need ugly hacks :) and this is not a big project  to advise bootstrap, it is just a coding question :)

Answer (score 3):

As i already suggested in my comment, you better don' try to use an element to define or manipulate the behaviour of another element.

So in your case, you probably want to know how to make your footer stick to the bottom of the page, while your content takes up all the remaining space between your header and your footer.

There are of course several ways, a basic approach could look like this:

```
<div id="header">
   Some content here..
</div>

<div id="content">
   Your content here...
</div>

<div id="footer">
   Some stuff here..
</div>
```

with a css like this:

```
#header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

#content {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background: green;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

As you see, for this example the header does nothing special. It takes up `100px` at the top of your page and stretches to `100% width`.

The Footer is set to `position: fixed` at the bottom ( `bottom: 0 or 0px` ), takes up `50px` height and stretches also `100% width` of its parent container (in our case it's our body).

A little bit more special is our div `#content`. First we position it `absolute` at the `top` (with the height of our `#header`) and make it take up all of the `width`.

Then we have to cover several scenarios:

1. First scenario: We have no actual content in our `#content`. To make the div stretch to to the bottom until it hits the footer, we have to set `bottom: 50px`.
2. Second scenario: Our content takes up more space then we see: If this is the case, as soon as you scroll down the background wouldn't be filled anymore ( in our case green ), because of this, we add `display: table` to make our div stretch its dimensions always to the same height of its inner contents (Our text for example).

And finally, because our `#footer` is positioned `fixed` and would lay over our `#content` we have to add `padding-bottom: 50px` to our `#content`.

---

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gzrLg27d/) for you with this example.

Comment: I don't want a content div, I just want a header and a footer. That's why I thought adding an empty div might be a good idea.

Comment: Well with my suggestion you could just remove the `#content div`.

Comment: You edited the comment many times and I didn't see the full explanation. Now it makes it a bit more sense in my head as I don't really understand how positioning works. Yet. Thx a lot :).

Comment: Yes sorry, i figured a little explanation would be helpfull. No problem. Try to understand what i did there since this is a pretty common approach of a basic page layout. Of course there are variants especially regarding `display: table`. But well, you said you don't want any content for now anyway, so the footer and header markup is all that matters for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want by using the `flexbox`, with this you don't need to work with fixed `height` in `header`/`footer` or even the middle div `#empty_div`

I also tweaked you code a bit.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
html {
  font-size: 14px;
  /* changed for demo */
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/200/300') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: cover
}
#wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
/*-------------- HEADER -----------------------*/

#header {
  display: flex;
  font-family: "Frijole", cursive;
}
#header h1 {
  padding-left: 20px
}
#header nav {
  margin-left: auto
}
#header ul {
  padding: 20px 20px 0 0;
}
#header li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}
/*-------------- EMPTY DIV -----------------------*/

#empty_div {
  flex: 1;
  background: red
}
/*-------------- FOOTER -----------------------*/

#footer {
  text-align: center
}
#footer p {
  margin: 5px 0
}
.social_icon {
  display: inline;
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  margin: 0 0.3215rem 0 0
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="header">
    <a href="index.html" id="logo">
      <h1 class="headings">THE 100 DAYS PROJECT</h1>
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="new_treehouse.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="empty_div"></div>
  <div id="footer">
    <a href="http://twitter.com/cilvako">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="Twitter Logo" class="social_icon">
    </a>
    <a href="http://facebook.com/">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="Facebook Logo" class="social_icon">
    </a>
    <p>&copy; 2016 Silvia Bogdan</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want/need the middle div, you can still use `flexbox` like this:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
html {
  font-size: 14px;
  /* changed for demo */
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/200/300') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: cover
}
#wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
/*-------------- HEADER -----------------------*/

#header {
  display: flex;
  font-family: "Frijole", cursive;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, .7)
}
#header h1 {
  padding-left: 20px
}
#header nav {
  margin-left: auto
}
#header ul {
  padding: 20px 20px 0 0;
}
#header li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}
/*-------------- FOOTER -----------------------*/

#footer {
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, .7)
}
#footer p {
  margin: 5px 0
}
.social_icon {
  display: inline;
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  margin: 0 0.3215rem 0 0
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="header">
    <a href="index.html" id="logo">
      <h1 class="headings">THE 100 DAYS PROJECT</h1>
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="new_treehouse.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <a href="http://twitter.com/cilvako">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="Twitter Logo" class="social_icon">
    </a>
    <a href="http://facebook.com/">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="Facebook Logo" class="social_icon">
    </a>
    <p>&copy; 2016 Silvia Bogdan</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to give the Head element a height because you didn't give it any height it thinks it has a height of 0 so it doesn't push the empty div down , so you see the overlap.

just enter this into the css under header and it will work fine.

`#header
{
    height:100px;
}`